# Multiple POST requests using Jmeter

Tags: post, jmeter, stress-testing

I have to do a stress test on my application to create 1000 users. In order to create a user I do a POST request using a json:

```
{
 "code": "string",
 "domainName": "string",
 "enabled": true,
 "name": "string"
}
```

I can't figure out how I am going to create more than one user with jmeter. Is there a for loop? Also how do I get around the fact that code has to be unique so each user would need a unique code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To create more virtual users just define as many as you like under [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

   [image: JMeter Thread Group 1000 users]
2. To send unique data you can replace your `code` value with i.e. [JMeter Function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html), something like:

   ```
           {
             "code": "${__threadNum}",
             "domainName": "string",
             "enabled": true,
             "name": "string"
           }
   ```

   The above example uses [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) which basically returns current virtual user number, so code will be `1` for first user, `2` for second user, etc. You can also consider the following alternatives:

   - [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) - generates a random string within the given range
   - [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) - generates a random string from given source data
   - [__UUID()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) - generates an unique GUI structure
   - [counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) - generates an incrementing number each time being called

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) for more information on JMeter Functions concept.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a Loop Controller and you can load data from CSV within that loop - have a look at [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7755746/1265200)

Answer (score 0):

Although using a loop would create your 1000 users, they would not execute at the same time. Assuming your intention is to execute a stress test with 1000 users doing requests concurrently a normal Thread Group would suffice.
You can use the CSV controller (http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to set up the different users so each thread has its own user variables. There are other Thread group controllers that you can use if you want more elaborate behavior.