# JMeter - How to execute multiple CSV Data Sets

Tags: jmeter

I have two CSV files, `test1.csv` and `test2.csv`. These two tests are slightly different, but I want to test them through the same test plan and report on them together. Therefore, I thought I would create two test fragments.

[image]

I have a thread group called `10 Concurrent Users` because it's a thread group that will have 10 threads. I want this thread group to first run the `Test 1` Test Fragment and then `Test 2` Test Fragment. I want each test fragment to end after the corresponding CSV file reaches EOF.

I understand I can set `Stop thread on EOF` to true, but I don't want to stop the thread. I just want to "end" this test fragment. How do I do this?

This is what my Thread Group looks like. I don't want it to run infinitely, and I don't want to hard code the number of iterations.
[image]

One way I found was to just have two separate thread groups. One thread group for the first CSV file and one thread group for the second CSV file. Set the Thread Groups to "Infinite" and have "Stop Thread on EOF" set to true for each Data Set Module. However, it would be nice to not have to have separate thread groups as they are just duplicates of each other

Comment: One way I found was to just have two separate thread groups. One thread group for the first CSV file and one thread group for the second CSV file. Set the Thread Groups to "Infinite" and have "Stop Thread on EOF" set to true for each Data Set Module. However, it would be nice to not have to have separate thread groups as they are just duplicates of each other.

Answer (score 1):

In same thread group define a [While Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755384/jmeter-loop-through-all-values-in-csv) per CSV Data Set Config

Define in While's condition the value you get from CSV

> Define an while controller with the Condition as ${url}

And don't recycle list on EOF:

> To stop execution after the end of the CSV file is reached: within the CSV Data Set Config set Recycle on EOF? = False and Stop thread on EOF? = True.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate all the values in the CSV file and then continue you can configure the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) like:

[image]

and put your Sampler(s) under the [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) using the following __jexl3() function as the condition:

```
${__jexl3("${myVar}" != "<EOF>",)}
```

Another option is putting the logic under the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller), the number of lines in the CSV file can be determined dynamically using the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)

```
${__groovy(new File('/path/to/your/file.csv').readLines().size(),)}
```